# Resolving Bot Identification Issues and Website Compatibility in Custom Chromium Build: Understanding the 'reese84' Cookie

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, chromium

I downloaded the Chromium browser source code for Windows using these instructions: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/114.0.5735.199/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Setting-up-Windows

After downloading, I ran the executable file of Chromium. However, I encountered issues with some websites not functioning correctly in Chromium but these websites are properly working in chrome and in other browsers, leading to an error message:

"Pardon the Interruption
As you were browsing, something about your browser made us think you were a bot. There are a few reasons this might happen:

You're a power user moving through this website with super-human speed.
You've disabled JavaScript in your web browser.
A third-party browser plugin, such as Ghostery or NoScript, is preventing JavaScript from running."

Upon investigating, I discovered that the error seems to be related to a cookie named "reese84." Deleting this cookie resolved the issue for some website links, but not for others. This "reese84" cookie is generated through browser fingerprinting, IP address, and other factors. It is a security cookie used by Imperva Incapsula, a web application firewall (WAF) and bot protection service. This cookie generates a unique fingerprint for each user to identify and block bots.

I am unsure why I am being identified as a bot, considering I only downloaded a fresh build of Chromium and ran it. I have also looked into repositories related to this cookie's creation, but their solutions have not worked for me.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to avoid being identified as a bot and how to make all websites run properly on Chromium, as well as a better understanding of how this "reese84" cookie is actually created.